# Two Radio buttons in list view

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list view  builder and In this list view I have two radio buttons and I want to be selected only one from entire list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NuJX.png)

Comment: You need to add your efforts in order to get helped in Stack Overflow. See [how to ask a good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
int groupValue = 0; // First radio is checked

// ...

ListView(
  children: [
    Radio(
      value: 0,
      groupValue: groupValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (mounted) setState(() {
          groupValue = value;
        });
      },
    ),
    Radio(
      value: 1,
      groupValue: groupValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (mounted) setState(() {
          groupValue = value;
        });
      },
    ),
  ],
),
```